# How to create Teechart in VB6?

Tags: database, vb6, teechart

How to create Teechart in VB6?

Answer (score 2):

you should follow this tutorial for using tee chart in VB 6.0

http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/java/v1/docs/Tutorials/tutorial6.htm

Answer (score 1):

Once you have installed TeeChart Pro ActiveX in our computer you need to:

1. Start VB6 Create a new application
2. Go to Project -> Components
3. Search for TeeChart on the list (pressing a 'T' is quicker :-P)
4. Enable TeeChart components in the list Press OK. Now you'll have TeeChart components in
   the toolbox.
5. Select TChart component in the component palette and add one
   to your form.
6. Double-click the form to generate the OnLoad event handler
7. Implement the OnLoad event like this:

Private Sub Form_Load()

```
TChart1.AddSeries scBar

For i = 0 To 10
    TChart1.Series(0).Add Rnd, "", clTeeColor
Next
```

End Sub

This will plot a bar series with 10 random values. For further information I strongly recommend you to read the tutorials and the features demo included with the installation and available at TeeChart's program group.